# Keeping whatsapp installed on second device

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

If I transfer everything over wireless to my new android device (included whatsapp) from the old one, when I open Whatsapp it does not ask a verification code for the new device (where I have my sim). And in the old device, with just wifi, the old whatsapp still works. 
How can that be possible?

Comment: Saying "transfer (included whatsapp)" you mean what? Did you install whatsapp on the new phone? Can you start WA on the new phone?

Comment: From the old android phone to the new android phone all apps (whatsapp included) were copied through wireless. So i didn't install any app. All the apps in the old device were found in the new device. And upon opening whatsapp I just entered in the chat page without the app asking me any verification code

Comment: Are you trying to say that WhatsApp is now working on both devices at the same time?

Comment: I uninstalled whatsapp on the old device after 10 minutes. So I don't know if the app would have stopped by itself automatically or not. But in those 10 minutes yes I could open both

Comment: Do you know how could that be possible?